# Magento 2.4.6-p3 price error FR after upgrading

Tags: 2.4.6-p3

I performed an update to version 2.4.6-p3 of Magento. I have two stores: one for French (Fr) and another for English (Eng). I am using the Tigren Ajaxcart module to display a popup when adding items to the cart, allowing users to select options.

Prior to the update, everything was functioning correctly. However, after the update, I encountered an issue specific to the French store (Fr). When clicking on the cart, the price is displayed as 0.00. On the English store (Eng), everything continues to work as expected.

EDIT : For information : For Fr I have : priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': {"productId":12,"priceFormat":{"pattern":"CHF\u00a00.00" For Eng I have : priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': {"productId":12,"priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s" How can I fix this problem for the Fr version?

Comment: Any help please i'm blocked

Answer (score 0):

For information :
For Fr I have : priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': {"productId":12,"priceFormat":{"pattern":"CHF\u00a00.00"
For Eng I have : priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': {"productId":12,"priceFormat":{"pattern":"%s"
How can I fix this problem for the Fr version?